# Can I add a calendar event to my Android from from a website?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android app I can use this intent to launch the Add event activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

intent.putExtra("beginTime", timestamp);
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);

intent.putExtra("endTime", timestamp+toAdd);
intent.putExtra("title", name + " at " + venue);
intent.putExtra("eventLocation", venue);
```

Can I somehow do this on a mobile website?

Comment: There is no direct way of doing this. You can use GCM for this purpose by but it is not intended to be used in that way

Answer (score 0):

Could create a [VCALENDAR file](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45664?hl=en) like. After download the file, it would be insert in your calendar app